# Is there a Spring Annotation for Error Handling that is not MVC related?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop

I have a bunch of Processors (basic data saving objects) that are currently in one big transaction. If one of them fails (duplicate data or whatever) I loose all the data.

I want to put the individual Processors into their own transactions so won't loose data.  I can do that with annotations and all is fine.  However, I have to catch the exceptions and only throw certain ones (like database down or some such).  I want to eat the other errors (duplicates and bad messages and values and such) and just log them.

I found the ErrorHandler interface in Spring and the this thing:  `@ExceptionHandler(NullPointerException.class)`

but I want something that is not tied to MVC.  So I want something like this:

```
try {
   <!--wrapped code (processor) -->
} catch (exception) {
   <!--Exception handler code. -->
}
```

@ExceptionHandler(myexceptionHandler)

Also, I do understand that I can do this with AOP, but I would rather have a Spring stock class/annotation  (I want someone else to do the work...)

It seems that Spring would have something like this built in, but I haven't found it.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you want a `try / catch` block AND an annotated method?

Comment: why do you not want it to be tied to the MVC?

Comment: Because I am not using Spring MVC...